# Why does my do while loop never end? C++

Tags: c++, do-while

```
int main ()
{

int wordCode;

const int QUIT_MENU = 9;
```

Menu

```
do
{
    cout << "Given the phrase:" << endl;
    cout << "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their ___.\n" << endl;
    cout << "Input a 1 if you want the sentence to be finished with party." << endl;
    cout << "Input any other number for the word country.\n" << endl;
    cout << "Please input your choice now." << endl;
    cin  >> wordCode;
    cout << endl;
    writeProverb(wordCode);

while (wordCode >= 1 || wordCode <= 2)
{
        cout << "You have not entered a valid selection." << endl;
        cout << "Please eneter a 1 or a 2." << endl;

    }

    if (wordCode != QUIT_MENU)
    {
        switch (wordCode)
        {
            case 1:
                writeProverb(wordCode);
                break;
            case 2:
                writeProverb(wordCode);
        }
    }
```

Is the proper way to exit this loop?

```
}while (wordCode != QUIT_MENU);

return 0;
}
```

Start of void function to write proverb.

```
void writeProverb (int wordCode)
{
 //Fill in the body of the function to accomplish what is described above

if (wordCode == 1)
{
    cout << "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their party." << endl;
}

if (wordCode == 2)
{
    cout << "Now is the time for all good men to come to aid the aid of their country." << endl;
}

}
```

"You have not entered a valid selection."
"Please eneter a 1 or a 2."

The above text keeps repeating no matter what value is selected.

Answer (score 4):

Why should it?

```
while (wordCode >= 1 || wordCode <= 2)
```

User enters:

```
           wordCode >= 1      wordCode <= 2            
1              True                True            -> True  || True -> True
-1             False               True            -> False || True -> True
2              True                True            -> True  || True -> True
3              True                False           -> True  || False -> True
999999         True                False           -> True  || False -> True
-99999         False               True            -> False || True -> True
```

no matter what number the user enters, the condition can literally never become false.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
while (wordCode >= 1 || wordCode <= 2)
```

to

```
if (wordCode == 1 || wordCode == 2)
```

You don't want that part to loop; the outer `do/while` handles that just fine. You just need to output the message once.

Comment: How is that different to `if (true)`

Answer (score 0):

To add to Marc B's answer, I think you want     `while (wordCode == 1 || wordCode == 2)`

Answer (score 0):

Change "while (wordCode >= 1 || wordCode <= 2)" to "while (wordCode >= 1 && wordCode <= 2)".  That should fix your loop.